# Is my deck ready to be painted

Tags: deck

I power washed my deck and want to try a sample spot for paint. Is the right half ready for paint or does it need any more cleaning? Please see pics. Just want to be cautious and not damage the wood.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question cannot be answered with 100% certainty ... only a guess can be given ... a physical examination of the deck is required if you want a 100% certainty, which your question is asking for

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @jsotola, it can't be certain.

The colour looks a bit uneven in the last photo, Maybe you can get it more even with another wash.  But you dont want to be too aggressive.

There are black spots, you need to examine them to see what they are.  Ensure they are not spongy.  If there any deep gashes, then consider a filler.

If the surface feels uneven, I would give the whole deck a very light sand.